# Loop Function to find 14 digit numbers and run a script for those results - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**Preface:** I have two textareas. I want to paste a list of unformatted phone numbers to produce a list of phone numbers in a certain format. I figured out how to remove dashes, commas, spaces and letters to just produce the format I need. (I made it add a comma and a space and remove the last comma fyi)

**Issue:** The current code below works great in the order of the .replaces. I tried to group those together and it didn't work as well with some examples but breaking it up so it flows in that order seemed to work. However, I often have phone numbers of ranges. So if you have 555-555-5555 - 5556, it will output 55555555555556. 14 characters! I wondered if there was a way to "find" these 14 characters after this formula is ran and use another code I figured out (below the one below) to output the ranges for those numbers. I will post both codes below and finish my thought. Ideally, I want to combine both formulas.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function textremv() {
let output = Array.from(
    new Set(
        document.getElementById("content").value
        .replace(/,/g, "") // replace commas with nothing
        .replace(/\n/g, ",\n") //replaces new lines with comma and new line
        .replace(/\s|-/g, "") // replaces space and dash with nothing
        .replace(/[{()}]/g,"") //replaces all special characters with nothing
        .replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "") //replaces a-z with nothing
        .replace(/,/g, ",\n") //replaces comma with comma linebreak
        
        
        .split(',')
        
        

    )
).join(", ");
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML = output + " "; //adds space at the end

}

// [0-9]{10}-[0-9]{4} 
}
function ct() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("content2");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  /* <input type='button' value='Extract Text2' onclick='sortvalues(0);ct()'/> */
}
</script>

<form name="sorter">
<textarea rows='10' cols='20' id='content'></textarea>
<textarea rows='10' cols='20' id='content2'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='textremv();ct()'/>


</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Single range works with code below such as 5555555555-5556 will give both phone numbers listed out.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function listrange(){
var range = document.getElementById("listrange1").value
var range1 = range.slice(0,10);
var range2 = range.slice(0,7) + range.slice(12,15);
var text = "";
var i = range1;
while (i <= range2) {
  text += i + ", ";
  i++;
}
document.getElementById("listrange2").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>

<textarea rows='10' cols='20' id='listrange1'></textarea>
<textarea rows='10' cols='20' id='listrange2'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='Extract Text' onclick='listrange()'/>
```

**Summary:** I'm not sure if there is a way to combine the formula to take those 14 characters and then run it against the second script I have there to produce the list of phone number ranges.

Example would be like this:

555-555-5555
123-456-7890-7891
555-555-5506

Should return an output of:
5555555555,
1234567890,
1234567891,
5555555506

I am just not sure how to make it retrospectively go back and look for those 14 characters to apply that loop function.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit: Scott's answer worked!! In case you're coming across this question and are inexperienced as I am, here's the full code for you to play around with. This code assumes you are providing 10 digit phone numbers or 10 digits with a 4 digit range. Ex: 1234567890 or 1234567890-7899**

```
<textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='listrange1'></textarea>
<textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='listrange2'></textarea>
<br>
<button id='extract' >Extract Phone Numbers</button>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
const getRange = (str) => {
  const [_, intro, start, end] = str .match (/(\d{6})(\d{4})(\d{4})/)
  return Array.from({length: end - start + 1}, (__, i) => intro + String(+start + i).padStart(4, '0'))
}

const phoneNumbers = str => 
  str .split (/[,\s]+/)                    // break on commas and/or spaces
    .map (str => str .replace (/\D/g, '')) // remove non-digits
    .filter (Boolean)                      // remove empties
    .filter (str => str .length == 10 || str.length == 14)
    .flatMap (str => str .length == 14 ? getRange(str) : [str])

document.getElementById('extract').onclick = (evt) => 
  document.getElementById('listrange2').innerHTML = 
    phoneNumbers(document.getElementById('listrange1').value).join('\n')
    </script>
```

Searchable keywords: Javascript, phone number, ranges, phone number range, client-side, loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that didn't really look at your code but wrote it from scratch:

```js
const getRange = (str) => {
  const [_, intro, start, end] = str .match (/(\d{6})(\d{4})(\d{4})/)
  return Array.from(
      {length: end - start + 1}, 
      (__, i) => intro + String(+start + i).padStart(4, '0')
  )
}

const phoneNumbers = str => 
  str .split (/[,\s]+/)                    // break on commas and/or spaces
    .map (str => str .replace (/\D/g, '')) // remove non-digits
    .filter (Boolean)                      // remove empties
    .filter (str => str .length == 10 || str.length == 14)
    .flatMap (str => str .length == 14 ? getRange(str) : [str])

const text = `First is 555-555-5555, more here: 123-456-7890-7893,
and a range starting at 0: 555-666-0000-0004
and another two: 555-555-5506 and 202-456-1414` 
                                  // ^-- (White House switchboard, if you need it)

console .log (phoneNumbers (text))
```

- **`getRange`** takes a 14-digit string and creates all the phone numbers in the range.  (There is no error-checking that the end of the range is higher than the beginning; you might want to add that.)
- **`phoneNumbers`** breaks the string into chunks at spaces characters and commas, removes all non-digit characters from each resulting string, removes any strings that are now empty, and then uses `getRange` for the 14-digits ones.  It uses `flatMap` to take the plain phone numbers and the arrays of them returned by `getRange` and flatten them into a single list.

You might want to do a further `filter` to remove the numbers that aren't of length 10 or 14.  That would probably go right before the `flatMap` call.

### Update: use with text areas

This captures the information in one text area and extracts the phone numbers when the button is pressed:

```js
const getRange = (str) => {
  const [_, intro, start, end] = str .match (/(\d{6})(\d{4})(\d{4})/)
  return Array.from(
      {length: end - start + 1}, 
      (__, i) => intro + String(+start + i).padStart(4, '0')
  )
}

const phoneNumbers = str => 
  str .split (/[,\s]+/)                    // break on commas and/or spaces
    .map (str => str .replace (/\D/g, '')) // remove non-digits
    .filter (Boolean)                      // remove empties
    .filter (str => str .length == 10 || str.length == 14)
    .flatMap (str => str .length == 14 ? getRange(str) : [str])

document.getElementById('extract').onclick = (evt) => 
  document.getElementById('listrange2').innerHTML = 
    phoneNumbers(document.getElementById('listrange1').value).join('\n')
```

```html
<button id='extract' style="float:right">Extract Phone Numbers</button>
<textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='listrange1'>First is 555-555-5555, 
more here: 123-456-7890-7893, 
and another two: 555-555-5506 and 202-456-1414
and a range starting at 0: 555-666-0000-0004</textarea>
<textarea rows='6' cols='50' id='listrange2'></textarea>
```

Comment: I can see the end results works when I ran the Run code snippet. I'm really embarrassed to ask, but here it goes. How can I make the const text pull results from one text area say named "listrange1" and output to another textarea named "listrange2"?

Comment: @traveler84: added an HTML snippet

Comment: Thank you! That made sense with the example you provided. However, I'm bumping into an issue where test number/range 5555000000-3000 is returning without the zeros. 

5555000
5555001
5555002
...

Comment: I've been staring at it for a bit. I think it's the intro, start, end part. When it's telling it to end - start, I think the system is getting confused with 0's minus 3000 in the example I provided earlier. It doesn't seem to realize it should be leading zeros until 4 digits are provided otherwise. Is there a way to declare that in the loop?

Comment: @traveler84: you're right, there was a bug which I fixed above with `padStart`.  I also fixed another one while I was at it, skipping those numbers which aren't either 10 or 14 digits long.  (There is now a `0` in the text, which was showing up in the lists.)

Comment: Thank you Scott for following up on this!! I've worked on this task for over 10 years on and off and given up each time. Now I have something to play around with and I'll work on removing special characters and whatnot. Short term, I can use my original code to "wash" the numbers and then paste into your script.

Comment: Glad it worked.  But next time, please don't wait ten years to ask for help!